# React memo function with isEqual

Tags: reactjs, memo

I have this React.memo component that I want to render only if the props doesn't change with sending a second argument isEqual function.
When I console.log the wrapper component and the memmoized component I can see that its being rendered with the same props.. What am I doing wrong?

My wrapper component

```
export const WrapperComponent= props => {
    console.log('MemoizeComponent', props);
    return (
       <MemoizeComponent name="memo"/>
    );
}

export const WrapperComponent;
```

My memmoized component

```
export const Component = props => {
    console.log('component: ', props.name)
    return (
       <div>{props.name}</div>
    );
}

function isEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
    console.log(prevProps.name);
    console.log(nextProps.name);
    return prevProps.name === nextProps.name;
};

export const MemoizeComponent = React.memo(Component, isEqual);
```

console output:

```
memo
memo
component:memo
memo
memo
component:memo
```

Comment: `I want to render only if the props doesn't change with sending a second argument isEqual function` that sounds like an opposite to what `React.memo` does - prevent re-render if props didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is but your code as is works correctly:

```js
const { useState, memo, useRef } = React;
const useRendered = () => {
  const rendered = useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return rendered.current;
};
function App() {
  const [, setRender] = useState();
  const rendered = useRendered();
  return (
    <div>
      <div>rendered {rendered} times</div>
      <button onClick={() => setRender({})}>
        re render
      </button>
      <WrapperComponent name="memo" />
    </div>
  );
}

const WrapperComponent = props => {
  return <MemoizeComponent name="memo" />;
};
const Component = props => {
  const rendered = useRendered();
  return (
    <div>
      {props.name} rendered {rendered} times
    </div>
  );
};

function isEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.name === nextProps.name;
}

const MemoizeComponent = memo(Component, isEqual);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: And if the wrapper component renders again. Will it render again the memmoized component even though props.name didn't change?

Comment: @LilacEilim wrapper will always re render because it's a functional component. The component passed to React.memo will only re render if props change, you could see that in the example